# Identify and label episodes based on ID and dates

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010

My data contains multiple rows for each ID (column A) with corresponding episode dates (column B).  I want to calculate how many different episodes each ID has and label them from 1 onwards based on which date is earliest.  If a date occurs twice for the same ID these should be recorded as the same episode number:

[image: example]

I want the formula to return the values displayed in column C.

Many thanks for your help with this query.

Comment: have you tried pivot table ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but I really needed a formula - I'm happy to say I have this now

Comment: cool, welcome to the site ! you can accept an answer as correct by the way, this helps others see it worked, look for the tick next to the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have already down the hard work by sorting your data.  In **C1** enter ***1***. In **C2** enter:

```
=IF(A1<>A2,1,IF(B1=B2,C1,C1+1))
```

and copy down:

[image]

Comment: This is perfect - many thanks for your help - it is very much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep the labels in row 1 like in your example, and data is sorted for column A and then column B, you can use this formula in C2: `=IF(A1="ID";1;IF(A2=A1;IF(B2=B1;C1;C1+1);1))` and copy down.
(Note: My excel implementation uses semicolon instead of comma between arguments)